# I tried to baked my high poly sculpt onto my low poly retopo, but it didn't work? what happened?

Tags: sculpting, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

Okay so I watched a tutorial on how to do the baking and stuff and got this result:

[image]

The uv editor shows a janky version of my high poly sculpt but nothing else has changed, my low poly mesh looks exactly the same as it did before no matter what viewmode i go into. what happened and why isn't it working?

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you have baked a *Normal* map? Even it goes totally wrong a normal map is a light purple image, especially where it's empty. Your baked texture has no color and it's black where it's empty. It looks like you baked the diffuse color 2) make your low-poly object *[Shade Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/shading.html)* in object mode. If you don't do this the blocky edges will be baked on the image

Comment: 3) I am not sure if you're aware of this, to see a difference after you baked the image you need to connect *Image Texture* node to a *Normal Map* node (add this node). Then connect this to the *Principled BSDF* node. Set *Color Space* of the *Image Texture* node to *Non-Color*.

Answer (score 0):

in bake/ selected to active/ play with extrusion and Max ray distance. you can turn render sampling down to do fast test